# A resource reference binding could not be found for "xxx" resource reference,

Tags: java, websphere

I was trying to deploy my EAR but it shows error as:

```
InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the GlobISDatasource resource reference, defined for the GlobIS component.
[11/10/16 16:20:35:196 IST] 00000027 InjectionEngi E   CWNEN0011E:  The injection engine failed to process bindings for the metadata.
[11/10/16 16:20:35:198 IST] 00000027 ComponentName E   CNTR0125E: Unable to process injection information for class: [].
[11/10/16 16:20:35:235 IST] 00000027 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0015E: Failure to initialize Web application GlobIS
[11/10/16 16:20:35:237 IST] 00000027 DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, GLOBISWeb.war, of application, GlobISswati.ear/deployments/GlobISswati, failed to start..
```

Comment: This error message is poor, and it's unclear how the application managed to be installed without a proper binding.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: I have binding xml  then also it shows as issues with the resource reference binding

Comment: What do the issues look like if you have a binding?